# What does <a href="#">Click here</a> mean?

Tags: html

What does `<a href="#">Click here</a>` mean?

Answer (score 24):

It means "Render a hyperlink that takes the visitor to the top of the page and label it with the, distinctly uninformative, text *Click here*"

Comment: technically it may not be the top of the page - it may be an anchor to somewhere else on the page or it may be the click event that fires a jquery event

Comment: @Paul — no. "#" is the top of the page. "#something" could be a different part of the page, but # alone is the top.

Comment: @Paul — and there *might* be a click event attached to the element that overrides the normal behaviour, but the quoted code is just a link to the top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a  href="#Bookmark1" target="frame1">
  Link text that leads to Bookmark1 in the current document
</a>

<a  href="http://www.foo.com/index.html#Bookmark1" target="frame1">
  Link text that leads to Bookmark1 in index.html at www.foo.com
</a>
```

If no Bookmark is specified in the HREF statement, the browser will default to the top of the document.

From [Hyperlink [A Href]](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/a/a-hyperlink.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The # of the link [Click here](http://#) is link to the top of the current page. But these kind of **#** links are often also used for links that are generated by JavaScript. With modern JavaScript library like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) it is no longer needed to explicitly add an "[onClick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)" attribute to the html, see for example the JQUery API: [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/).